# String.format with English local but numbers are arabic

Tags: android, locale

I am calculating **priceAfterDsicount** then place value in EditText(so user can modify it after App calculation)

Value retured from **format** is arabic numbers
this is code

```
    private fun handleDiscount() {
        val price = edPackagePrice.text.toString().toDoubleOrNull()
        val discount = discount_percentage_edit_text.text.toString().toIntOrNull()
        "handleDiscount before price$price discount$discount".log(mTag)
        price?.let {
            discount?.let {
                val finalValue = String.format("%.1f", ValuesHelper.getPercentage(price, discount),Locale.US)
                price_after_discount_edit_text.setText(finalValue)
                "handleDiscount ook price$price discount$discount, final $finalValue".log(mTag)
            }
        }

        if (discount == null) {
            "handleDiscount $price , ${edPackagePrice.text}".log(mTag)
            price_after_discount_edit_text.setText("")
            price?.let { price_after_discount_edit_text.setText(price.toString()) }
        }
        "handleDiscount after  price_after_discount_edit_text${price_after_discount_edit_text.text.toString()} ".log(mTag)
   
    }
```

Output at Run

[image]

so what is problem?

**NOTE**

- App language is arabic(user can change it from app).
- I found other way to convert arabic number to english

Comment: how did you resolved this issue ? I am facing same issue

Comment: @YeshaShah i solved with looping on numbers and replace them. found code here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Use Java.math.BigDecimal ,it will automatically construct English numeric equivalent to Arabic numeric equivalent , After you have English numeric equivalent do your calculation and when you want to update the UI after calculation use the device locale to show the end result to user in Arabic , BigDecimal only work with digits i.e. 0123. For special characters like , you have to do exception handling , we have .isDigit() method of Character class that you can leverage to iterate over whole input string and remove , before doing calculation,hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help, But I need to want why String.format with local not work as expected.